# How do I get a recursive daily average for one month?

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I need a daily average for an entire month, but the trick is that all of the clients have different start and end dates.  For example, some clients are only enrolled for part of the month.  Assume client A is enrolled from 4/3/13-4/8/13, client B from 4/6-4/30, client C from 4/1-5/1, etc.  How can I achieve this?  Here is my current code which returns super low counts because it assumes all clients are enrolled the entire month:

```
if exists (
    select  * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o    where o.xtype in ('U')  and o.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#enrollments_PreviousMonth2')
) DROP TABLE #enrollments_PreviousMonth2;

Select
    people_id,
    program_modifier,
    program_modifier_id,
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, actual_date)) as enroll_midnight_date,
    actual_date as enroll_start_date,
    end_date as enroll_end_date

INTO #enrollments_PreviousMonth2 
From
 program_modifier_enrollment_view pmev with(nolock) 
Where
program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' and
actual_date  <= '4/30/13' and (end_date >= '4/1/13' or end_date is null)

;with cte as (
select cast(enroll_start_date as date) as actual_date,
    count(people_id) cnt
From #enrollments_PreviousMonth2 en
left join Calendar c on en.enroll_midnight_date = c.dt
where program_modifier_id = 'E1AA7A36-0500-4BAE-A0AA-D9E0BC91A6F3' 
    AND enroll_start_date  <= '4/30/13' and (enroll_end_date >= '4/1/13' or enroll_end_date is null)
Group by enroll_start_date--, enroll_end_date, program_modifier_id, program_modifier
)
select  
sum(cnt*1.0)
from cte
```

I prefer to not use a CURSOR for the solution, however.

Comment: Your query looks a little too intricate to analyze without source tables and data. I suggest mocking up some sample data along with the query in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), then link to the fiddle here along with a comment showing the desired output.

Comment: Not sure what it is you're trying to get an average of (or what's recursive about this question for that matter), but can't you just do a datediff between the start and end enroll dates to get the number of days each client has been enrolled?  I see enroll_end_date in your code but it's commented out.